# How to check in laravel if a method of some service is called in codeception functionall test

Tags: laravel, tdd, codeception

I have a `codeception` `cest` test in which I want to check if some method is called.

```
public function my_test(FunctionalTester $I)
{

    $I->authenticateTestUser($I);
    $this->fillKomitentForm($I, 'kom1', 'Komitent 1');
    $I->click('btnSave');

    // Here I want to check that MyService.myMethod() is invoked

}
```

I can make a helper but anyway I do not know how to assure that some method on some object is called. Take into account that this is `Laravel 5.2` and that those services are bind using service providers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [AspectMock](https://github.com/Codeception/AspectMock).

One of the features is `Create test doubles for class methods called anywhere`.